# How to combine functionalities of SourceWithContext and SourceQueue in Java?

Tags: java, akka-stream

I want to create a Akka stream `Source` to which I'm able to push data whenever my API endpoint is called. Also, I want to pass context/metadata along with elements. I checked out `SourceQueue` which supports pushing elements. There is `SourceWithContext` which allows passing context/metadata along with elements. `SourceWithContext` supports operations which automatically propagate the context of an element. I want to combine these two functionalities i.e. I want push mechanism along with automatic context propagation.

Comment: `SourceWithContext[Out, Ctx, Mat] ` is just a thin wrapper around `Source[Pair[Out, Ctx], Mat]` - you can make a `SourceWithContext` from a `Source` with `SourceWithContext.fromPairs`. As such, you could make a `SourceQueue` that expects to have `Pair[Out, Ctx]` enqueued and then make a `SourceWithContext` out of that.

Comment: @Alec: Thanks for the help. I could write code based on your suggestion. Will be posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

PFB code based on the approach suggested by @Alec:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
        SourceQueueWithComplete<Pair<Integer, String>> sq = Source.<Pair<Integer, String>>queue(10, OverflowStrategy.backpressure())
                .asSourceWithContext(Pair::second)
                .map(Pair::first)
                .to(Sink.foreach(param -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture(param).thenAccept(System.out::println)))
                .run(system);
        // Pushing elements in the SourceQueue (sq) created above
        List<Pair<Integer, String>> list = List.of(Pair.create(1, "one"), Pair.create(2, "two"));
        list.forEach(pair -> sq.offer(pair));
    }
```